# React Native Webview: How to trigger function once on onScroll?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to trigger the reload function on scroll position. I set below code to trigger reload when contentOffset.y is smaller than -180 but it's being triggered multiple times as contentOffset.y's position keeps changing.

How do I make sure that reload is only triggered once?

```
_onScroll = (event) => {
  if (event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y < -180) {
    this.webView.ref && this.webView.ref.reload();
    console.log("Triggered multiple times as event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y is keep changing")
  }
};
```

Here is the WebView where it gets the scroll position.

```
<WebView
  bounces={true}
  onScroll={this._onScroll}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way to tell your component that you have already run the scroll reload, then only run the reload function if it hasn't been run before. **The best way to do this is in the component's state:**

```
_onScroll = (event) => {
  if (event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y < -180) {
    !this.state.scrollReloaded && this.webView.ref && this.webView.ref.reload();
    this.setState({ scrollReloaded: true });
  }
};
```

The above solution works but is not as performant; `_onScroll` will still get called every time we scroll. This gives you extra flexibility but is tougher on the CPU. For **slightly** better performance you can add this:

```
<WebView
  bounces={true}
  onScroll={e => !this.state.scrollReloaded && this._onScroll(e)}
/>
```